# /usr/ucb/ps output redirection yield truncated line

Tags: unix, solaris

/usr/ucb/ps command output to screen shows a long list envrionment variable and its values, but when redirecting output to a file yields a truncated line.

How to explain this?

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/ucb/ps -auxwee 6543 >/var/tmp/env-var 2>&1

bash-3.2$ cat /var/tmp/env-var
USER       PID %CPU %MEM   SZ  RSS TT       S    START  TIME COMMAND
alcrprun  6543  0.0  0.0 8752 5992 ?        S 19:35:01  0:15 /usr/bin/python -Bu ./bin/dpfoservice.py CFG_HOME=/opt/apps/algo/algoS

bash-3.2$ /usr/ucb/ps -auxwee 6543
USER       PID %CPU %MEM   SZ  RSS TT       S    START  TIME COMMAND
alcrprun  6543  0.0  0.0 8752 5992 ?        S 19:35:01  0:15 /usr/bin/python -Bu ./bin/dpfoservice.py CFG_HOME=/opt/apps/algo/algoSuite.current.solaris.alcr/cfg RISK_HOME=/opt/apps/algo/algoSuite.current.solaris.alcr/risk++ ALGO_HOME=/opt/apps/algo/algoSuite.current.solaris.alcr ARE_HOME=/opt/apps/algo/algoSuite.current.solaris.alcr/aggregation/are 
...
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints a 132-wide output to a file because that's what the `-w` argument does.  Per [the `ps.1b` man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7mif/index.html):

> -w
>
> Uses a wide output format (132 columns rather than 80); if repeated, that is, `-ww`, use arbitrarily wide output. This information
>   is used to decide how much of long commands to print.

If you want arbitrary-width output, use `-ww` instead of `-w`.

When using just the `-w` option and the output is a terminal window, `/usr/ucb/ps` appears to detect the terminal width on my copy of Solaris 11 - changing the width of the window modifies the amount of output emitted with just the `-w` option.  The documentation for that behavior is likely buried somewhere on a Solaris man page, give the historical nature of Solaris documentation.

Comment: Thanks! You solved my problem: just use www instead of w.

Answer (score 0):

```
# /usr/ucb/ps -aux | head
```

> USER       PID %CPU %MEM   SZ  RSS TT       S    START  TIME COMMAND
>   orabudge 13285  4.1 51.18413180884116344 ?        O 08:56:30  0:22 oraclebudget (LOCA
>   orabudge 11998  3.4 51.18413552884119456 ?        O 08:51:53  1:49 oraclebudget (LOCA
>   root       732  3.1  0.0    0    0 ?        S   Feb 04 326:27 zpool-budgetdb_dat
>   orabudge 12030  2.8 51.18413296884116648 ?        S 08:52:02  2:04 ora_p004_budget
>   orabudge 12034  2.8 51.18413284084116504 ?        S 08:52:02  2:04 ora_p006_budget
>   orabudge 12032  2.8 51.18413290484116568 ?        S 08:52:02  2:04 ora_p005_budget
>   orabudge 12036  2.7 51.18413296884117176 ?        S 08:52:02  2:02 ora_p007_budget
>   orabudge 21339  1.0 51.18414346484127680 ?        S 07:18:27  4:24 oraclebudget (LOCA
>   orabudge  4347  0.9 51.18414084084125256 ?        S 08:19:23  1:10 oraclebudget (LOCA
>   [root@budgetdb:ravi]#

**USER** – User who started the process.

**PID** – Process ID number assigned by the system.

**%CPU** – Percentage of the CPU time used by the process.

**%MEM** – Percentage of the total RAM in your system in use by the
process (it will not add up to 100 percent as some RAM is shared
by several processes).

**SZ** – Amount of nonshared virtual memory, in Kbytes, allocated to
the process. It does not include the program’s text size which is
normally shared.

**RSS** – Resident set size of the process. It is the basis for
%MEM and is the amount of RAM in use by the process.

**TT** – Which "teletype" the user is logged in on.

**S** – The status of the process.

**S** – Sleeping

**O** – Using cpu (on CPU) or running

**R** – Running and waiting for a CPU to become free

**Z**– Terminating but has not died (zombie)

**P** – Waiting for page-in

**D** – Waiting for disk I/ O

Check disk performance and memory usage if many
P or D statuses appear. This could indicate an overload of both subsystems.

**START** – Time the process started up

**TIME** – Total amount of CPU time the process has used so far

**COMMAND** – Command being executed